# stuck with MOK management blue screen

Tags: lenovo, bios

I have a Lenovo Z50-70 and I got affected by Bug [corrupted BIOS due to Intel SPI bug in kernel](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1734147),
now my bios is blocked and I can't access Ubuntu  to solve this  issue . 
When I open my laptop I got this blue screen:

[image: MOK management blue screen]

When I click on continue, it automatically boots windows.

Is there any method to boot Ubuntu?!

Notice that I can't change secure boot status or boot from any usb or  DVD because of bug

I was on ubuntu  18.04 updated from  ubuntu  17.10 
 dual boot with windows 10

Comment: Hello Tawfiek Khalaf , and welcome to Ask Ubuntu! In order to increase that chances that somebody gives a good answer to your question,  please provide more information. What Ubuntu Version do you use? What is this Bug#17... There exists so many buglist. Add this information in your original post.

Comment: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1734147 is the bug they're referring to.

Comment: ok but I can't access ubuntu to solve the issue

Comment: @TawfiekKhalaf you can try booting into Windows like you said it was, and then download the BIOS for the computer from the manufacturer and reflash it.  But it may or may not work.

Comment: I tried to do that put I have the latest version already installed  @ThomasWard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this issue by reprogramming my bios. out of the motherboard.